# How to add border to Select2 element with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

I'm trying add border to Select2 with jQuery, but it's not working.

JavaScript:

```
 $('#search').click(function () {
        if ($('#select :selected').text() == ""){
            $('#select').addClass("alert");  
        } 
});
```

CSS:

```
.alert
{   
    border: 2px solid red !important;
}
```

HTML:

```
<select style="width:300px" id="felevselect">
     <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected"></option>
</select>
<select style="width:120px" id="napselect">
     <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected"></option>
     <option value="1">Hétfő</option>
     <option value="2">Kedd</option>
     <option value="3">Szerda</option>
</select>
<select style="width:90px" id="select">
     <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected"></option>
     <option>8:00</option>
     <option>9:00</option>
     <option>10:00</option>
     <option>11:00</option>
</select>
<button id="search" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Keres</button>
```

How to add border to only one Select2 element?

Comment: For starters your missing the `border-style` in your shorthand css declaration for `border`.

Comment: The `alert` class is already added? can you check that?

Comment: Thank you! Updated!

Comment: Yes, alert class added, but not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I got you correctly, here is working code:

**HTML**

```
<select style="width: 100px;" id="my-select">
    <option value="1">Item1</option>
    <option value="2"></option>
    <option value="3">Item2</option>
</select>
<button>Click me!</button>
```

**CSS**

```
.alert {
    border: 2px solid red !important;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('select').select2();
$('button').on('click', function() {        
     if ($('#my-select :selected').text() == ""){
         $('.select2').addClass("alert");
     }

     // using following code you can toggle alert class
     // $('.select2').toggleClass("alert", $('#my-select :selected').text() == "");
 });
```

Also provided [**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/m-dehghani/pen/rrapjG)

As you know, when using `select2`, this plugin hide the `select` element and show you some generated `HTML` (instead of `select`), *you can check the generated html using browser's console*

**Update**

If the `#select` is your target, you can change the code to following, then your mentioned issue (*in comment section*) will be fixed:

```
$('#select').next().addClass("alert");
```

Answer (score 0):

You got to handle it within on change handler

```
$('#select').on('change', function(){
  if ($('#select :selected').text() == ""){
    $('#select').addClass("alert");  
  } 
});
```

Comment: button click function...    $('#search').click(function () {...}

Answer (score -1):

Here is a working example.

```
$( '#btnTest' ).click(function() {
  if ($('select :selected').text() == ""){
    $('select').addClass("alert");  
  } else {
    $('select').removeClass("alert");  
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/WordyTheByrd/f772n4je/

Comment: button click function... $('#search').click(function () {...}

Comment: Check my edit.  Hopefully that answers any questions.

Comment: Thanks, but doesn't working with me select2. Add alert class is work. css not!